# PHP Checkbox Filtered SQL List Without A Table Structure

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, checkbox

I'd like to be able to filter a list of SQL results using php checkboxes but without having the data displayed in a table.

I've found (and tried) tutorials on this kind of thing but can figure out how to manipulate them to fit my needs (I'm by no means a coder, I've learnt as I've gone along but cant seem to figure this one out!)

I've got my page [HERE](http://www.our-pub.co.uk/Tameside-Food-Guide/MenuPageTest-v3.php) which is a dynamically built list of food items from my database. My filter lists are also built dynamically from the options in the relevant columns in my food items table...

Filter Code Example...

```
<?php
    $sql = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM food_items 
    INNER JOIN directory
        ON food_items.author = directory.author    
    ORDER BY directory.area
    ";

$result = $con->query($sql);        
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
        {        
            $areaFilter = '';
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                if($areaFilter != $row["area"])
                {
                    $areaFilter = $row["area"];
                    echo '<div><input type="checkbox" id="id_' . $areaFilter . '" name="' . $areaFilter . '"><label for="AreaStalybridge">' . $areaFilter . '</label></div>';
                }
            }
        };

?>
```

And here's the code for the dynamic list of food items, grouped by course...

```
    <?php
        $sql = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM food_items 

        INNER JOIN directory
            ON food_items.author = directory.author

        INNER JOIN courses
            ON food_items.course_id = courses.course_id

        ORDER BY food_items.course_id
        ";

    $result = $con->query($sql);        
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
            {        
                $curCategory = '';
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    if($curCategory != $row["course"])
                    {
                        $curCategory = $row["course"];
                        echo '<p class="menuCourseHeader"><strong>' . $curCategory . '</strong></p>';
                    }
                        echo 
                            '<div class="menuItemContainer">
                                <div class="menuItemContainerLeft"> <p class="menuVenue">' . $row["pub_name"] . '</p><p class="menuVenue">' . $row["area"] . '</p> </div>
                                <div class="menuItemContainerMain">
                                    <p class="menuItem">' . $row["item"] . ' - £' . $row["price"] . '</p>
                                    <p class="menuDescription">' . $row["description"] . '</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="menuItemContainerRight"><p class="menuVenue">' . $row["course"] . '</p> </div>
                            </div>';
                }
            };
    echo '<hr/>';

$con->close();
    ?>
```

From what I've found up to now, my best bet is to use Ajax to post a separate 'submit.php' file each time a checkbox is ticked to return a new filtered list but as I said earlier, i'm no coder and can't seem to find anything close enough to what I need to be able to manipulate it.

If anybody can point me in the right direction, your help would be very much appreciated.

Cheers,
Mark.

Comment: you are not using WHERE anywhere in you SQL query, I don't know how does your table schema look like but I guess it should look like this
`SELECT * FROM food_items 
        INNER JOIN directory
            ON food_items.author = directory.author
        INNER JOIN courses
            ON food_items.course_id = courses.course_id
        WHERE area = 'Denton'
        ORDER BY food_items.course_id`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
As far as I know, the SQL will need to change dynamically as checkboxes are ticked, eg when somebody ticks "Denton" then the `WHERE area = 'Denton'` will be added to the query and a new set of results returned?

Comment: Well, you can do this in that way OR get all data only once and then filter them dynamically only by javascript like in this example 
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/draxo

Comment: Cheers for that mate, look interesting! I'll have a proper look and see if I can use it to work for me. Thanks again, your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is this reading a database or is it just creating the filterable items on the fly?

Comment: Well I guess this is reading database only once and then filter items on the fly by just displaying them on your page or not.